# LED strip doesn't turn off completely by transistor

Tags: transistors, leakage-current

I've made a circuit with a touch switch module turning on/off a LED strip via a transistor, and the whole thing works, but in the "off" state the LED strip still shines a bit.
[image: touch switch led circuit]
Touch switch module I'm using:
[link to aliexpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/10PCS-LOT-Touch-Sensor-Jog-type-touch-module-capacitive-touch-buttons/32416625224.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4_10152_10065_10151_10068_436_10136_10137_10157_10060_10138_10155_10062_10156_10154_10056_10055_10054_10059_100031_10099_10103_10102_10096_10147_10052_10053_10107_10050_10142_10051_10170_10084_10083_10080_10082_10081_10110_10111_10112_10113_10114_10181_10183_10182_10185_10078_10079_10073_10070_10123,searchweb201603_9,ppcSwitch_3&btsid=fe398804-d243-470f-a728-542a497fff19&algo_expid=13681893-6bf9-4d19-af6c-abf66aafb50a-1&algo_pvid=13681893-6bf9-4d19-af6c-abf66aafb50a)
(I've configured it to work in latch mode)

The touch switch module is supposed to have `0V` in `off` state, so the transistor should be in a "closed" state. Why is it allowing some current to flow through emitter-collector?

What can I do to make it turn off completely?

In the "on" state everything is fine, and touch-switching works well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sensor is trying to drive the transistor's base to 5V in the off state (because with a 5V supply the sensor can't output more than 5V), and its emitter is at 12V. (Given that the transistor is not on fire, it's safe to assume the emitter-base voltage is not actually 7V, and the output resistance of the sensor is limiting the current. This should not be relied upon; you should put a resistor in series with the base.) This forward-biases the emitter-base junction, driving the transistor into saturation or forward-active (depending on circuit conditions) and allowing current to flow.

If you want to use a 5V signal to switch 12V power, you'll want to use an NPN transistor on the low side; this transistor as it is won't turn off until you apply 12V to it.

Comment: Do you mean I should use NPN instead of PNP? I didn't understand what is "the low side".

So if I keep using this transistor - can I fix the circuit by adding some resistors?

So the base-emitter voltage should be less than `1.4V` for transistor to shut down?

Didn't realize PNP is so different from NPN, thx! :) will read more about it :)

Comment: The emitter-base voltage should be less than 0.6~0.7V for it to turn off. Likewise, in an NPN transistor, the base-emitter voltage should be less than 0.6~0.7V to turn off. It's easier to treat them as current-controlled devices though. No, you can't fix it with resistors, you would need a level shifter of some sort which is more complicated than you need. "the low side" means put the transistor on the low-voltage side of the LEDs; NPN transistors are typically used with their emitters at or near ground potential.

Comment: One way to think about it is like this: ignore the collector of the transistor and just treat the emitter-base (or base-emitter) junction like a diode, directed in the same direction as the arrow in the symbol. If that diode is forward-biased, the transistor is either in saturation or forward-active mode, and it is conducting.

Comment: Can you recommend some popular NPN transistor with 1A or more max current? :) To replace this TIP32.

Comment: Sure, I'd suggest a TIP31 or if you want to really over-spec it, a D44H8. But you can also always just use [Digi-key's parametric search](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/discrete-semiconductor-products/transistors-bipolar-bjt-single/276), instead of having to ask around!

Comment: With TIP31 on the low side it works as expected! Thanks!